# Saving Image as Blob file to google app engine using jesery

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, google-cloud-datastore, blob

I want to save a image as a blob file in the datastore. I have written a module class for the object using JPA:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class PotholeMedia {

@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long pothole_media_id;
private int pothole_Id;
private Blob image;

//Default constructor
public PotholeMedia (){}

//Overloaded constructor
public PotholeMedia(Long pothole_media_id, int pothole_Id, Blob image) 
{
    super();
    this.pothole_media_id = pothole_media_id;
    this.pothole_Id = pothole_Id;
    this.image = image;
}//end constructor


/**
 * Gets pothole_media_id attribute
 * @return Long
 */
public Long getPotholeMediaId() 
{
    return pothole_media_id;
}//end getPotholeId method



/**
 * Sets pothole_media_id attribute
 * @param pothole_media_id
 */
public void setPotholeMediaId(Long pothole_media_id) 
{
    this.pothole_media_id = pothole_media_id;
}//end getPotholeMedia method



/**
 * Get pothole_id attribute 
 * @return
 */
public int getPotholeId() 
{
    return pothole_Id;
}//end getPotholeId method



/**
 * Set pothole_id attribute
 * @param pothole_Id
 */
public void setPotholeId(int pothole_Id) 
{
    this.pothole_Id = pothole_Id;
}//end setPotholeId method



/**
 * Get image attribute
 * @return Blob
 */
public Blob getImage()
{
    return image;
}//end getImage method



/**
 * Set image attribute
 * @param image
 */
public void setImage(Blob image) 
{
    this.image = image;
}//end setImage method


 }//end PotholeMedia class
```

My problem is that I don't know how to save this using jersey this is what I have tried so far.

```
    @POST
@Path ("/save/image")
@Consumes (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveImg (@FormParam ("file") PotholeMedia media)
{
    try
    {
        EntityManager manager = EMF.getInstance().createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(media);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        return Response.status(Status.OK).build ();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build ();
    }
}//end saveImg method
```

Is this the correct way to save the object or how should I, if not.

Comment: what's your client html code?

Comment: I am using android to send image from the camera to save it on the app engine